# Creating clickable areas on a png of lakes without the using <map>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I've been racking my brain over the following, I'll try and be as specific as I can:

I've got a single image of 5 lakes as an element on a site I designed. I'd like to make each individual lake clickable so that I can utilize lightbox to pop up maps of each lake.

Here's the catch - I'd use map tags to sort this out, but I'd need to define absolute height and width to provide coordinates for the areas; which I've avoided defining so that my page scales properly on mobile devices or when windows are re-sized.

what is the most effective way of accomplishing this?

I've attached an image of the lakes. The url for the site is: http://pfowp.lowertownish.com/

[5 lakes each need to be clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWXdb.jpg)

If it helps to see the code, here it is:

```
<div id="select" style="font-size:20px; text-align:center; display:block;">
    <h2 class="lakesHead">Choose Your Get-A-Way!</h2><hr>
    <img class="landscape" src="/img/theLakes.png" />
    <a href="/reservations/"><button style="text-shadow:0 0 10px white; padding: 20px 35px; color:#264368; font-weight:900; margin: 25px auto 40px; display:block;" class="btn btn-warning shadowMedium"> BOOK YOUR TRIP NOW  </button></a>
    <p id="foodList" style="margin-top:20px"><em>Our remote Canadian lakes offer some of the finest Canadian walleye and trophy northern fishing anywhere. The famous Ogoki and Albany River system have many rapids and pools, which result in excellent spawning and reproduction. As a result the fishing is consistent in its high quality...spring, summer or fall. This water system is not only home to trophy fish but numbers of fish caught during your fishing trip to Canada.</em></p>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, or even a point in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick way if you do not want to use `<map>`.

Place the image as background of a `div` having `background-size:cover;`.

If you split the [lakes image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWXdb.jpg) in 9 square `div` elements and bind a click event on each using unique ids you can also preserve the aspect ratio you want in mobile devices

- lake 1 is top left
- lake 2 is top center
- lake 3 is top right
- lake 4 is middle left
- no lake in middle center
- lake 5 is middle right
- lake 6 is bottom left
- lake 6 is bottom center
  lake 5 is bottom right